# ETS does not seem to store my insert

Tags: erlang, ets

I'm trying to implement a process that I can query/update for some state information (I'm working on an SMS service and want to store some local data based on responses - later I will use a DB but for now I want to use ETS, this is my first Erlang project so I think it's useful to learn). Unfortunately it seems like my inserts are not coming through and I don't understand why. This is the module:

```
-module(st).
-compile(export_all).

maintain_state() ->
    Tab = ets:new(state, [set]),
    receive
        {Pid, lookup, Key} ->
            Pid ! ets:lookup(Tab, Key),
            maintain_state();
        {Pid, update, Key, Handler} ->
            NewState = Handler(ets:lookup(Tab, Key)),
            Status = ets:insert(Tab, NewState),
            Pid ! {Status, NewState},
            maintain_state();
        {Pid, statelist} ->
            Pid ! ets:tab2list(Tab),
            maintain_state();
        kill ->
            void
    end,
    ets:delete(Tab).

start_state_maintainer() ->
    Pid = spawn(st, maintain_state, []),
    register(state, Pid).

update_state(StateHandler) ->
    state ! {self(), update, testing, StateHandler},
    receive
        After ->
            After
    after 1000 ->
            throw("Timeout in update_state")
    end.

lookup_state() ->
    state ! {self(), lookup, testing},
    receive
        Value ->
            Value
    after 1000 ->
            throw("Timeout in lookup_state")
    end.

all_state() ->
    state ! {self(), statelist},
    receive
        Value ->
            Value
    after 1000 ->
            throw("Timeout in all_state")
    end.
```

Which I then load in an erl session:

```
> c(st).
> st:start_state_maintainer().
> st:lookup_state().
[]
> st:update_state(fun (St) -> {testing, myval} end).
{true, {testing, myval}}
> st:all_state().
[]
```

Since `update_state` shows `true` I figured the insert was successful, but nothing seems to be stored in the table. What am I doing wrong?

PS: if this whole approach is flawed or you have other remarks about my code I would appreciate those as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. Let's run your code again.

```
1> c(st). % compile your code
{ok,st}

% Before doing anything. let's get count of all ETS tables using ets:all/0
2> length(ets:all()). 
16 % So the Erlang VM has 16 tables after starting it

3> st:start_state_maintainer().
true

% Let's check count of tables again:
4> length(ets:all()).          
17 % Your process has created its own table

5> st:lookup_state().
[]

% Check count of tables again
6> length(ets:all()).
18 % Why????

7> st:update_state(fun (St) -> {testing, myval} end).
{true,{testing,myval}}
8> length(ets:all()).                                
19

9> st:all_state().   
[]
10> length(ets:all()).
20
```

So in line 5 in function `maintain_state/0` you are creating an ETS table and in lines 9, 14 and 17 you are calling this function again ! So after receiving each message (except `void`) you are creating new ETS table!
Let's see those tables:

```
11> P = whereis(state). % Get process id of 'state' and assign it to P
<0.66.0>
12> Foreach = 
fun(Tab) -> 
    case ets:info(Tab, owner) of 
        P -> % If owner of table is state's pid
            io:format("Table ~p with data ~p~n"
                      ,[Tab, ets:tab2list(Tab)]); 
        _ -> 
            ok
    end 
end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.118419387>

13> lists:foreach(Foreach, ets:all()).
Table 28691 with data []
Table 24594 with data []
Table 20497 with data [{testing,myval}]
Table 16400 with data []
ok
```

And after killing your process, We should have 16 tables again:

```
14> exit(P, kill).
true
15> length(ets:all()).                                                                                                                      
16
```

You have two choises. You can use named tables like this:

```
maintain_state() ->
    % With 'named_table' option, we can use the name of table in code:
    Tab = ets:new(state, [set, named_table]),
    maintain_state2().

maintain_state2() ->
    receive
        {Pid, lookup, Key} ->
            Pid ! ets:lookup(state, Key), % I used name of table
            maintain_state2();
...
```

Or use table as argument of `maintain_state2`:

```
maintain_state() ->
    Tab = ets:new(state, [set]),
    maintain_state2(Tab).

maintain_state2(Tab) ->
    receive
        {Pid, lookup, Key} ->
            Pid ! ets:lookup(Tab, Key),
            maintain_state2(Tab);
...
```

I changed the code to one of above examples and here is the result:

```
1> st:start_state_maintainer().
true
2> st:lookup_state().
[]
3> st:update_state(fun (St) -> {testing, myval} end).
{true,{testing,myval}}
4> st:all_state().
[{testing,myval}]
5> length(ets:all()).
17
```

After playing with Erlang's message passing and understanding its functionality and its concepts, I really suggest you to learn OTP design principles and OTP behaviors like [gen_server](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) and use them instead of writing your own `receive ...` and `Pid ! ...` statements.

Comment: Ah I see, I should have been able to catch that error :) I thought maybe there was some system for transactions that I didn't know about and that I needed to commit my inserts or so. Thanks for the advice about OTP, I will definitely look into that.